# Antonia and David are playing a game. Each player starts with 100 points

Tags: python, dice

Question: Antonia and David are playing a game. Each player starts with 100 points. The game uses standard six-sided dice and is played in rounds. During one round, each player rolls one die. The player with the lower roll loses the number of points shown on the higher die. If both players roll the same number, no points are lost by either player. Write a program to output the final scores and the winner

Input Specification The first line of input contains the integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 15), which is the number of rounds that will be played. On each of the next n lines, will be two integers: the roll of Antonia for that round, followed by a space, followed by the roll of David for that round. Each roll will be an integer between 1 and 6 (inclusive). Output Specification The output will consist of two lines. On the first line, output the number of points that Antonia has after all rounds have been played. On the second line, output the number of points that David has after all rounds have been played.

One of my many problems is making the program list the correct number of inputs the first input specifies.

Here is what I have so far:

I know I only asked for one thing specifically, but can anyone complete this challenge so I can see what I can add to my program

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: rounds = input()
score1 = input()[0:3]
score2 = input()[0:3]
score3 = input()[0:3]
score4 = input()[0:3]

game = [score1, score2, score3, score4]

antonia = 100
david = 100


for scores in game:
    roll = game
    a = game[0]
    d = game[2]
    if a > d:
        antonia -= int(d[0])
    elif d < a:
        david -= int(a[2])
    elif a == d:
        break
print(antonia)
print(david)

Comment: Kinda lost on how to do this program as it is my homework and I'm confused

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a homework question, you really should try to it yourself first. With this being said, I will give you hints but I will not give you a full working program - I hope you can understand my reasoning for this.

To start, this problem definitely calls for some type of iteration as rolling a dice for n amount of times is repetitive. Whether you choose a `for` loop or a `while` loop is up to you - in this example I use a `while` loop. After getting the amount of rounds (don't forget to convert the user input into `int`), you can write something like this:

```
while rounds > 0:
   # simulate rolling here
   rounds -= 1
```

Rolling a dice is a random action - there is a 1/n chance to roll a number where n is the number of sides on the dice. I would suggest creating a list of all possibilities:

```
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And then use `choice()` from the `random` module to select a random item from this list.

```
from random import choice

david_roll = choice(dice)
antonia_roll = choice(dice)
```

Now that you have the values of each roll, you can just perform some simple comparison on the rolls:

```
if david_roll > antonia_roll:
    # modify scores accordingly
elif david_roll < antonia_roll:
    # modify scores accordingly
```

Comment: Thank you, ill try it out with your suggestions :)